# How to get version of required package

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm writing some test code to verify that a node install is sane.  As part of the process, I need to fetch and print the version of each module that is required by mine.  It would be a bonus if I could also get the versions of all the modules it depends on. How can I do this?

I know I could `require` the package.json for a module, but how do I find the path to the package.json for a module that has already been required?

I have looked at the `require` interface, which provides a `resolve` function, but this this gives the path to the main file loaded in the project.  In some projects, this can be in a completely different directory than package.json, and I don't want to have to write logic which tries to guess where package.json is relative to this.

I also looked at the `pkginfo` module, but this seems to require that you pass the `module`, and when I `require` a module I don't get that, I get `module.exports` instead.